# Increasing PODS not improving the Performance

Tags: kubernetes, kafka-consumer-api

I have a Consumer Application which currently running with 9 PODS and 50 Kafka Partitions of topic to which it is listining. Pods configuration are:

```
  min:
    cpu: 5
    memory: 8G
  max:
    cpu: 7
    memory: 8G
```

My one batch is taking around 22 mins to get completed. In order to improve the performance I increase the pods to 20 but i am not seeing any improvement in the performance, one batch still takes 22 mins to complete.

Can anyone helps what i am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

Adding more pods won't help on the performance so much.  Try adding a Vertical Pod Autoscaler to ramp up the CPU for the workload.

You'll need to ensure your cluster has VPA enabled and add a VPA YAML to the deployment (assuming CronJob here):

```
apiVersion: autoscaling.k8s.io/v1
kind: VerticalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: <name>
spec:
  targetRef:
    apiVersion: "batch/v1"
    kind:       CronJob
    name:       <name>
  updatePolicy:
    updateMode: "Auto"
```